# how to make a python module that automatically copy a dll into user's project root folder?

Tags: python, c++

So I have a c++ program which rely on a dll(lets call it `mtmanapi64.dll`) and a header file. Then I made a python module using c++ boost.python so that I can call the header file functions in python.

The problem is every time in order for me to call the c++ functions, I need to actually copy that `mtmanapi64.dll` file into python project's root folder. I am wondering that is there anyway I can write in my python module project so that when user install the module(or import the module) it will automatically copy the dll into project root folder(or looking for the dll inside the python site-package folder?)

python module project structure:

```
|   .gitignore
|   example.py
|   install.bat
|   MANIFEST.in
|   mtmanapi64.dll
|   requirements.txt
|   setup.py
|   symbols.raw
|   symgroups.raw
+---.idea          
+---env            
+---logs
\---py_mt4manapi
    |   boost_locale-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.dll
    |   boost_python36-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.dll
    |   boost_system-vc141-mt-x64-1_67.dll
    |   cppMt4ManagerApi.exp
    |   cppMt4ManagerApi.iobj
    |   cppMt4ManagerApi.ipdb
    |   cppMt4ManagerApi.lib
    |   cppMt4ManagerApi.pdb
    |   cppMt4ManagerApi.pyd
    |   cppMt4ManagerApi.pyd.lastcodeanalysissucceeded
    |   demo.py
    |   mt4_creds.ini
    |   python36.dll
    |   py_mt4manapi.py
    |   py_mt4_position_helper.py
    |   __init__.py
    |
```

c++ code request for dll file in root folder:

```
class CManager
{
    CManagerFactory   m_factory;
    CManagerInterface *m_manager;
#ifndef _WIN64
    LPCSTR dll_path = "mtmanapi.dll";
#else
    LPCSTR dll_path = "mtmanapi64.dll";
#endif


public:
    CManager() : m_factory(dll_path), m_manager(NULL)
    {

        char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];
        if (!GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath)))
        {
            printf("current path error.");
        }
        cCurrentPath[sizeof(cCurrentPath) - 1] = '\0'; /* not really required */
        printf("The current working directory is %s\n", cCurrentPath);
        m_factory.WinsockStartup();
        if (m_factory.IsValid() == FALSE || (m_manager = m_factory.Create(ManAPIVersion)) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Failed to create MetaTrader 4 Manager API interface\n");
            return;
        }
    }

    ~CManager()
    {
        if (m_manager != NULL)
        {
            if (m_manager->IsConnected())
                m_manager->Disconnect();
            m_manager->Release();
            m_manager = NULL;
        }
        m_factory.WinsockCleanup();
    }
```

Comment: That's usually a job for your build system and/or application installer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl as far as I know, install a python package is just go into the python package file folder and do `pip isntall .` Then it will build the python package by using whatever in `setup.py`. However, even if i included all the dll files, it will only put the files into python's site_packages folder instead of put it into project root folder.